# Pulse audio set rear speakers to be boosted?

Tags: pulseaudio

So I have a 4.0 speaker system set up and when all else is equal my rear speakers are noticeably quieter. I would like to set those speakers to be boosted to even out with my front one. In PAVU, after splitting up my channels I can set my rear speakers to have about  +7.50 db to my front speakers and they sound right. But when I attempt to adjust audio in my tray all the channels revert to the same db level.

Is there a way to set the rear speakers to have a permanent +7.50 db to the regular volume, such that, when I change the volume from the desktop tray the rear speakers will keep the +7.50 db level to the front ones?

KDE, Manjaro 4.9.0

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using?

Comment: AFAIK there's no [Pulseaudio module](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/) to modify mixing/volume, so I'd try to configure ALSA with a [route plugin](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html), and then make Pulseaudio use this ALSA device instead of the hardware one. But it's a bit of a pain to setup.